# How can I sort my bundler dependencies between being a dev dependancy or not?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

This has always been a thought of mine. I understand the difference between a dev dependancy or a dependancy not being one. Is there a way however of finding out which one is needed only for dev, not knowing or being familiar with some the packages used?

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no guarantee that the listings in `package.json` aren't erroneously classified, looking in `dependencies` and `devDependencies` in `package.json` is the closest thing there is to an easy way to determine if a package is used only for dev or not.